# Magento Newsletter Transaction email template inline style CSS not working

Tags: magento

Transaction email template inline style css not working for only Newsletter subscribe or unsubscribe when changing from backend admin panel.

But seems working all others template. Also working changing newsletter subscribe or unsubscribe from front-end.

**Anyone please help. I think it is Magento issue.**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it

So the top of your template now has:

```
<!--@subject Newsletter subscription success @-->
```

and it has to be:

```
<!--@subject Newsletter subscription success @-->
<!--@styles
@-->
```